# Generating Images With Other Images

Tags: php, image, gd

I am trying to make a progress bar for my clan website that shows the progress the user has made from their current rank to their next promotion.  Basically, my for statements generate the bars that I want to display by progress.  I.E. if a user's progress is 25%, it will show 2 yellow bars and 8 black bars.  the yellow bars and black bars are seperate images, but I want to combine the output of this script into one single image.  I have an image.php script that outputs the results of the function calculations, but not as an image.  All the examples I saw on php.net use the background color, font, font color, etc, but all I want to do is combine the images into one.  What function should I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very simple by using PHP´s `imagecopy` function.

Examples are available here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

You just need to use the function as much times the user needs yellow/black bars.